# Deserializing base64 encoded byte arrays return different results in 2 JSON.net library versions

Tags: .net, json.net, base64

```
  JObject j = JObject.Parse("{'responseArray':'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAA'}");

  byte[] r = j["responseArray"].ToObject<byte[]>(JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings()));
```

Expected Output (works fine with JSON.net  v4.5.6.14930)

```
r =  {byte[24]}
        [0]: 0
        [1]: 0
        [2]: 0
        [3]: 0
        [4]: 0
        [5]: 0
        [6]: 0
        [7]: 0
        [8]: 0
        [9]: 0
        [10]: 0
        [11]: 0
        [12]: 0
        [13]: 0
        [14]: 0
        [15]: 0
        [16]: 0
        [17]: 0
        [18]: 0
        [19]: 0
        [20]: 1
        [21]: 0
        [22]: 0
        [23]: 0
```

Deserializing the above code in JSON.net v6.0.8.18111 gives errorneous result

Incorrect Output (JSON.net v6.0.8.18111)

```
r= {byte[16]}
    [0]: 170
    [1]: 170
    [2]: 170
    [3]: 170
    [4]: 170
    [5]: 170
    [6]: 170
    [7]: 170
    [8]: 170
    [9]: 170
    [10]: 170
    [11]: 170
    [12]: 170
    [13]: 171
    [14]: 170
    [15]: 170
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Note- 
The snippet in the question is part of a complex piece of code, where data comes in as JSON parameter to a WebMethod, The responsearray is a part of a complex object sent into the webmethod, that is why we use the JSON.net library for decoding.

Comment: It would help if you gave specifics. E.g. "...gives wrong result..." - what result, why is it wrong. Or, "... takes this erroneously..." - what is "this" here?

Comment: edited the question to be more specific

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

This is [fixed](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/574) in [Json.NET 7.0 Release 1](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2015/06/22/json-net-7-0-release-1-documentation-bug-fixes-performance).

**Original Answer**

This is a Json.NET issue.  The problem is that your string `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAA` just happens to be successfully parsable as a GUID, in [`JsonReader.ReadAsBytesInternal()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs):

```
            if (s.Length == 0)
            {
                data = new byte[0];
            }
            else if (ConvertUtils.TryConvertGuid(s, out g))
            {
                data = g.ToByteArray();
            }
            else
            {
                data = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
            }
```

At this traceback:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsBytesInternal() Line 517   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenReader.ReadAsBytes() Line 74 + 0x9 bytes C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader = {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenReader}, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract = {Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonPrimitiveContract}, bool hasConverter = false) Line 1853 + 0x8 bytes   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader = {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenReader}, System.Type objectType = {Name = "Byte[]" FullName = "System.Byte[]"}, bool checkAdditionalContent = false) Line 144 + 0x2f bytes   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader = {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenReader}, System.Type objectType = {Name = "Byte[]" FullName = "System.Byte[]"}) Line 710 + 0x52 bytes    C#
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader = {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenReader}, System.Type objectType = {Name = "Byte[]" FullName = "System.Byte[]"}) Line 689 + 0x11 bytes    C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(System.Type objectType = {Name = "Byte[]" FullName = "System.Byte[]"}, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer}) Line 1837 + 0x11 bytes    C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(System.Type objectType = {Name = "Byte[]" FullName = "System.Byte[]"}) Line 1811 + 0x3c bytes  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject<byte[]>() Line 1698 + 0x39 bytes   C#
```

As you can see, this short-circuits the base 64 decoding.  Ugly bug, and rather bad luck on your part to get that exact string.

To block Json.NET's inappropriate GUID recognition you can create your own global `JsonConverter` for byte arrays.  When you do, Json.NET will pass you the raw string without the "helpful" GUID pattern match:

```
public class ByteConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(byte[]);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } } // Use the default implementation for serialization, which is not broken.

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (string)JToken.Load(reader);
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        if (value.Length == 0)
            return new byte[0];
        return Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then, to set it globally:

```
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new ByteConverter() }
        };
```

This workaround restores the correct deserialization for byte arrays.

Comment: Nice demonstration of the bug and a good workaround suggested.  +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `JObject` has already parsed the `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAA` as a `string` (`j["responseArray"].Type` == `JTokenType.String`), so the `j["responseArray"].ToObject<byte[]>` isn't doing a de-base64.

You have to parse it directly to a `byte[]`, like:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public byte[] responseArray { get; set; }
}

MyObject cl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>("{'responseArray':'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAA'}");
```

Clearly you can do the `Convert.FromBase64String` "manually":

```
JObject j = JObject.Parse("{'responseArray':'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAA'}");
byte[] r = Convert.FromBase64String((string)j["responseArray"]);
```

Comment: i edited the question to be more specific. I think Convert.FromBase64String((string)j["responseArray"]); wont fit our requirement here.

Comment: @RuhaimIzmeth If you can do a `j["responseArray"]` then you can do a `Convert.FromBase64String((string)j["responseArray"])`. There is no way to simply use a `JObject.Parse` to directly deserialize a `byte[]`

Comment: @Ruhaim If you are interested, the bug/feature has been introduced in 6.0.4. Up to 6.0.3 it works as you expected. You can probably go to github and write them. The issue page is https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues

Comment: @RuhaimIzmeth But I see you already did it some hours ago :-) Still, you can use 6.0.3 while waiting for the fix and it will work correctly. It **isn't** already fixed in the beta 7.0.* branch

Comment: Thanks for the research mate :), i saw your comment in github