# Newtonsoft.json IsoDateTimeConverter and DateFormatHandling

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, deserialization, asp.net-web-api2

This is not an issue but concept I just want to make it clear.
When working with asp.net web api we use Newtonsoft.Json's **SerializerSettings**. In this setting we can set

```
jsonSetting.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
jsonSetting.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
```

I understood what *IsoDateTimeConverter* is doing but but not clear about *DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat*. It seems to be there is no effect of *DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat* if you still using *IsoDateTimeConverter*.

Still excepting some explanation who know about this.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have several different related questions.  Let's break them down:

**What happens when I add a converter for a type that is natively supported by Json.NET?**

If you do that, your converter *supersedes* the native Json.NET functionality.  For instance, you can [replace its serialization of `byte []` fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369274/deserializing-base64-encoded-byte-arrays-return-different-results-in-2-json-net/30384841#30384841).  Or you can change how it serializes and deserializes numbers: this slightly silly converter serializes integers by adding 1:

```
public class IntConverter : JsonConverter
{ 
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(int); }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return (int)JValue.Load(reader) - 1;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(1 + (int)value);
    }
}
```

**Why does Json.NET provide various `DateTime` converters as well as native support for multiple `DateTime` formats?**

This is explained in the documentation [Serializing Dates in JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)

> DateTimes in JSON are hard.
>
> The problem comes from the JSON spec itself: there is no literal syntax for dates in JSON. The spec has objects, arrays, strings, integers, and floats, but it defines no standard for what a date looks like.

The native support for dates handles some commonly encountered formats; if you have dates in some other format you can derive from [`DateTimeConverterBase`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DateTimeConverterBase.htm).  (For an example, see [How to convert new Date(year, month, day) overload with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577833/how-to-convert-new-dateyear-month-day-overload-with-json-net).)  Having done so, your converter will supersede the native conversion specified by [`DateFormatHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatHandling.htm).

**Why does Json.NET have a class `IsoDateTimeConverter` that seems to duplicate the functionality of `DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat`?**

This is a legacy class.  From [Serializing Dates in JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)

> From Json.NET 4.5 and onwards dates are written using the ISO 8601 format by default, and using this converter is unnecessary.