# Serializing a DataTable with byte[] column to json generate base64 string, but when deserialized, it generate a DataTable with string column

Tags: c#, datatable, json.net, base64, json-deserialization

I have serialized a DataTable with f1 column as byte[]. The column  is serialized to Base-64 string  as given below:

```
        [
          {
            "f1": "5hAAJEA=",
            "f2": "hi_all",
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "f1": "5hrwJEA=",
            "f2": "hi world",
            "id": 2
          }
        ]
```

I used the following code to serialize the datatable with Json.Net:

```
      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable, settings);
```

When deserializing  the json string to a DataTable,  a datatable object is generated with acolumn f1 as string (not byte[]) with the same value of base64 string.

I think that is expected because the datatable is a generic structure without schema.

I know that deserializing using `list<Dto>` with a property of type `byte[]` can restore the byte[], but that is not an option because I use the datatable for bulk insert in sql database and deserialization is done at runtime without pre-definition of `Dto(POCO)` class.

I can create a Typed DataTable from the table definition in the database.

I tried to use [ByteJsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30384841/3142139) ,but it can't help.

You can check  [the complete c# program online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9AhtbT) to show the problem: 
with a complete trace for json serialization/deserialization process.

**Update:**

I used TypeNameHandling =TypeNameHandling.Objects,  to keep data type in json and get json like:

```
        [
          {
            "f1": {
              "$type": "System.Byte[], mscorlib",
              "$value": "5hAAJEA="
            },
            "f2": "hi all",
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "f1": {
              "$type": "System.Byte[], mscorlib",
              "$value": "5hrwJEA="
            },
            "f2": "hi world",
            "id": 2
          }
        ]
```

Now f1 is of type   System.Byte[] and it's supposed that DataTableConverter create column of type byte[] not string.

When i try to deserialize, an exception error is fired:

> Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable: StartObject. Path '[0].f1', line 3, position 11

It seems that `DataTableConverter` can't handle $type/$value pair.

Check [the source code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DNexUe)

My question:

- How to resolve that error for DataTableConverter.
- How to deserialize a json string with  Base-64 string to byte[] column in  the DataTable.

Comment: "the datatable is a generic structure without schema" So use strongly typed deserialization instead of a generic structure. `"5hrwJEA="` is a string, no matter what is in it, and generic deserialization will not make it anything else.

Comment: The deserialization is done at runtime without pre definition of strong object, but i can create a datatable with the valid schema at runtime. How to deseriialize using Typed datatable with schema.

Comment: There's not enough information in the JSON to do what you want.  You would need to go through all the string-type columns and check to see whether all values in each can be converted to binary successfully using `Convert.FromBase64String()`.  The problem is that many commonly encountered strings are valid base64 -- basically any string that contains only the 52 capital and small letters and whose length is divisible by 4 passes the test.  For instance `"Help"`, `"File"` and `"overflow"` are all valid base 64.

Comment: As a workaround solution, I can create the  datatable with schema at runtime. How jsonconverter  use that typed datatable and fill the the column(s) of type byte[]  with Convert.FromBase64String(coresponding_json_token)

Comment: I update the question and add type byte[] in json, and get an error in deserialization.